# Same session requests in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am attempting to POST data to an API endpoint which requires X-CSRF-Token validation. I can fetch the token just fine however when I am trying to POST data using the X-CSRF token I am getting a 403 response. I believe this is because Zapier does not store session data between requests.

Is there any way either via a Javascript step or developer APP, to maintain the HTTP session?

Process:

1. Send GET request to API endpoint with custom header: **'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch'**
2. Retrieve and store returned token value
3. Create POST request with custom header: **'X-CSRF-Token': token_value**
4. Send POST request.

Answer (score 2):

Check out our included https://zapier.com/help/code/#storeclient-javascript - we don't have an example of that *exact* use case but you can definitely store data (including CSRF tokens) that way. You'll need to write all your own glue code (IE: maybe a `getOrCreateToken()` method that encapsulates all your token retrieval, storage logic).

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately session cookies are a protected header, thus I cannot pass them from one request to a second manually.I have tried the  credentials: 'include' option for fetch() but it does not seem to have any effect.